# Inserting a string at the end of every word of a string

Tags: c++, string, insert

I'm trying to add "ay" to the end of every word of a string I get via getline in cpp, but the result prints infinite "ay"s without breaking. I used the 'insert' function for this:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int add;
    string s;
    getline (cin,s);
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
    {
        if (s[i]==' ')
        {
            add=i-1;

            s.insert(add,"ay");

        }

    }
    cout<<s;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Don't modify the container that you are iterating over. Ever.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen In theory correct, but there are exceptions. Iterator invalidation is not an issue here because no iterators are used.

Comment: @bitmask It's still broken.

Comment: @bitmask one could say that index invalidation is the problem here ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After you add the `ay`, the index `i` needs to be updated, otherwise, you continue the index at the recently added `y`, and the previous space is found again. Just bump the index in the loop if `ay` is inserted:

```
if (s[i]==' ')
{
    add=i-1;

    s.insert(add,"ay");

    i += 2;  // bump i appropriately
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Suppose you type `a  b`. You encounter a space at index `1` and insert `ay` before that, then you will encounter the same space again, insert `ay` before it and so on.

Instead of looking for words manually it can be easier to use a stringstream:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int add;
    string s;
    getline (cin,s);
    std::stringstream ss(s);
    string word;
    while (ss >> word) {
        std::cout << word << "ay ";
    }
    return 0;
}
```